# Setting .libPaths() For Running R Scripts From Command Line Using Rscript.exe

Tags: r, windows, cmd

I am trying to run R scripts via BAT files on Windows Command Prompt.

The scripts require a few R packages such as `data.table`, `tidyR`, etc.

For operational reasons, all required R packages and dependencies (including `data.table`) are installed at `C:\Users\username\Documents\R\R-3.5.1\library`. I am not allowed to install RStudio in this environment.

When I try 
`"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" script.R`, I get an error similar to

> Error in library(data.table) : there is no package called 'data.table'
>   Execution halted

How can I set the `.libPaths` via Command Prompt to point to the correct location of the packages (i.e. to `C:\Users\username\Documents\R\R-3.5.1\library`)?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: how about adding: `.libPaths(paste("C:/Users/",Sys.getenv("USERNAME"),"/Documents/R/R-3.5.1/library",sep=""))` at the start of your script?

Comment: I think this question have no relation to the `batch-file` tag...

Answer (score 2):

*Disclaimer: I'm unfamiliar with `R`.*

From [R: Search paths](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/libPaths.html) :

> The library search path is initialized at startup from the environment
>   variable R_LIBS (which should be a colon-separated list of directories
>   at which R library trees are rooted) followed by those in environment
>   variable R_LIBS_USER. Only directories which exist at the time will be
>   included.
>
> By default R_LIBS is unset, and R_LIBS_USER is set to directory
>   ‘R/R.version$platform-library/x.y’ of the home directory (or
>   ‘Library/R/x.y/library’ for CRAN macOS builds), for R x.y.z.

An [environment variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-variables.html) can be created with `set VARIABLE_NAME=YOUR_VALUE` batch command.

So your batch file should probably be something like this:

```
cd /d "C:\INSERT_PATH_TO_DIRECTORY_CONTAINING_script.R"
set "R_LIBS=C:\Users\username\Documents\R\R-3.5.1\library"
"C:\Program Files\R\R-3.5.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" script.R
```

However for portability reasons (let's say a collegue asks for a copy of your script or your computer dies) I suggest putting the script, R library and batch file in a single directory, let's say `C:\Users\username\Documents\R`. The batch file `C:\Users\username\Documents\R\script.bat` becomes:

```
cd /d "%~dp0"
set "R_LIBS=%~dp0R-3.5.1\library"
"%PROGRAMFILES%\R\R-3.5.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe" "%~dpn0.R"
```

`%PROGRAMFILES%` environment variable expands to full path of `program files` folder, `%~dp0` [parameter](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) expands to full path of a directory that holds your batch file, and `%~dpn0` is a batch-file full path without extension.

*Notice that `%~dp0R-3.5.1` is not a typo because `%~dp0` includes trailing backslash.*

This way you can copy `C:\Users\username\Documents\R` to `D:\Users\SOMEOTHERNAME\Documents\R` and the script will still run.

If you create another version of your script, just copy the batch file so that it has same filename as your script but `.bat` extension instead of `.R` and it should call the new script - this has proven to be very handy when debugging and distributing scripts.

Alternatively, if you would rather install libraries separately you may want to use `%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%` which expands to `C:\Users\username`.

Extracting proper `Documents` folder path, as well as `R` installation path is possible but requires reading the registry and thus is a bit more complicated.