# Run R script from VBA

Tags: r, vba

I have tried several examples found on forums to run my R script from VBA, but it doesn't work. The R script works well alone. Here is the code I ran:

```
Sub RunRscript()

Dim shell As Object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
Dim style As Integer: style = 1
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim path As String
path = "RScript C:\Users\Documents\Code.R"
errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)

End Sub
```

I'm getting an error message saying that running object "IWshShell3" failed. Is there anything special to write on the R code prior to running this macro? Shall I load a package, or load the files in a specific folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, here is a solution working well:

```
Function Run_R_Script(sRApplicationPath As String, _
                    sRFilePath As String, _
                    Optional iStyle As Integer = 1, _
                    Optional bWaitTillComplete As Boolean = True) As Integer

Dim sPath As String
Dim shell As Object

'Define shell object
Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

'Wrap the R path with double quotations
sPath = """" & sRApplicationPath & """"
sPath = sPath & " "
sPath = sPath & sRFilePath

Run_R_Script = shell.Run(sPath, iStyle, bWaitTillComplete)
End Function

Sub Demo()
Dim iEerrorCode As Integer
iEerrorCode = Run_R_Script("C:\Program Files\R\R-3.6.1\bin\x64\Rscript", 
"C:\Users\myname\Desktop\Code.R")
End Sub
```

Comment: I could not get this to work at all. It returns Method 'Run' of 'IWshShell3' failed.

Comment: Change sPath = """" & sRApplicationPath & """" TO chr(34) & sRApplicationPath & chr(34) and this works.

Answer (score 1):

Your script is not able to find the executable (`RScript`).
Provide the absolute path, then it should work well.

See here on where to find it: http://datacornering.com/how-to-run-r-scripts-from-the-windows-command-line-cmd/

Edit:
I saw right now, that you could stumble into further problems regarding missing environments.
See here: [Setting .libPaths() For Running R Scripts From Command Line Using Rscript.exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153917/setting-libpaths-for-running-r-scripts-from-command-line-using-rscript-exe)

Comment: Thank you! Does that mean I should necessarily use a batch file and go through Notepad and Cmd? I'm not sure I understand how to apply this explanation to my VBA script (I'm very new at VBA)

Comment: As I don't use R at all, I cant state that explicitly. I would go and test if providing the absolute path already fulfills your needs. If not it seems that you will have investigate in that batch idea.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it.

```
Sub RunRscript1()
    Dim shell As Object
    Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    Dim waitTillComplete As Boolean: waitTillComplete = True
    Dim style As Integer: style = 1
    Dim errorCode As Integer
    Dim path As String

    ' path to R executable:  C:\your_path\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\bin\x64\R.exe
    ' path to R script:  C:\your_path\Documents\R\Download.r
    ' see more setup details here
    ' http://shashiasrblog.blogspot.com/2013/10/vba-front-end-for-r.html
    path = "C:\your_path\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\bin\x64\R.exe CMD BATCH --vanilla --slave C:\your_path\Documents\R\Download.r"
    'path = """C:\your_path\Documents\R\R-3.2.5\bin\i386"" C:\Users\rshuell001\Documents\R\Download.R"
    errorCode = shell.Run(path, style, waitTillComplete)
End Sub
```

Comment: Almost working with your second path! (the one without the CMD BATCH part)  It opens a window with R but says "ARGUMENT '[path to the script]' ignored