# use system2 from R 4.2 to execute cammand in 32-bit R

Tags: r, ms-access, 32bit-64bit, system2

In older versions of R (e.g., 4.0.5) I could load tables from MS Access using a command such as:

```
system2(paste0(R.home(), "/bin/i386/Rscript.exe"),script_path)
```

and the R packages DBI and odbc. The script looks like

```
library(DBI)
library(odbc)
ch <- dbConnect(odbc(), .connection_string = 'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};Dbq=filepath/DB.mdb;')
tab <- dbReadTable(ch, name = 'target_table')
save.image(file = 'out.RData')
```

And then I can load "out.RData" back into my 64- R session. Obviously, this does not work in R 4.2.X, because there is no longer support for 32-bit. But I thought I could still call the same older 32-bit version by explicitly specifying the filepath, such as

```
system2(paste0("C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.5/bin/i386/Rscript.exe"),script_path)
```

but it generates the following puzzling warnings and errors:

```
Warning message:
package 'DBI' was built under R version 4.2.3 
Error: package 'odbc' is not installed for 'arch = i386'
In addition: Warning message:
package 'odbc' was built under R version 4.2.3 
Execution halted
```

What is the reason for these odd messages, and is there a way I can still use the newer R versions to load in MS Access data? Am I stuck using older versions of R?
Or are there newer solutions where MS Access plays nicely with 64-bit R?

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13070706/how-to-connect-r-with-access-database-in-64-bit-window

Comment: It's looks as if your R-4.0 is using the same library path (for packages) as your R-4.2, which is a mistake. If you have another directory with older packages, use that instead. What is the output from `.libPaths()`?

Comment: @r2evans Brilliant! And in retrospect, obvious. you are absolutely correct. Answer below.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if your `R-4.0` instance is using the same library path (directory of packages) as `R-4.2`, which shouldn't happen (per R package preparation), and also shouldn't happen (since you clearly need some packages to remain "frozen" in your 4.0 instance, a state that may not be supportable in 4.2).

Check your `.libPaths()` in the R-4.0 instance and make sure that it is using a distinct path for its own packages. Since you're on Windows, this should include a directory such as `c:/Users/<username>/AppData/Local/R/4.0` (forward or back-slashes) and `.../4.2`.

I don't have windows/R up atm, but it's likely that `system2` is passing along the `R_LIBS_USER` env-var.

Comment: Thanks. R-4.0 still points to the correct path, but it seems that the path for the current session specifies the path for the script execution in system2 (unless I explicitly specify the path in the script, as I now do).

Comment: @GlennStauffer, see my edit, it might be an env-var thing. (For instance, `system2('echo', "$R_LIBS_USER")` shows me my current path, whereas doing the equivalemt in a bash terminal does not.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out, by @r2evans above, the issue was that, even though the script was being executed in an older version of `R.script.exe`, the library path still pointed to the library for the version of the current R session in which the `system2` function was run. I fixed this by adding the following line to the top of my R script (that was executed in the `system2` command (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53153917/setting-libpaths-for-running-r-scripts-from-command-line-using-rscript-exe)):

```
".libPaths(paste0('C:/Users/',Sys.getenv('USERNAME'),'/Documents/R/win-library/4.0'))"
```